# I can't get data from api with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, alamofire

I'm trying to make an IMDb-like application using the tmdb API, I've completed the first parts of the application, but I can't get the data from the API, I've been trying for more than a day, but I couldn't solve the problem.

`print(viewModel.movie?.results?[indexPath.item].originalTitle ?? "")` in cellForItemAt in homeViewController
As a result of this code, the originalTitle should be printed, but it does not print.

- NetworkHelper

```
    import Foundation
    enum  HTTPMethods: String{
        case get = "GET"
        case post = "POST"
    }
    enum    ErrorTypes: String,Error{
        case invalidData = "Invalid data"
        case invalidURL = "Invalid url"
        case generalError = "An error happened"
    }
    
    
    class NetworkHelper{
        static let shared = NetworkHelper()
        
        private let baseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/"
        private let apiKey = "509ef93252a59761a3c353f9ea114de0"
        
        func requestUrl(url: String) -> String {
       return baseURL + url + "?api_key=\(apiKey)"
           
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

- NetworkManager

```
    import Alamofire
    
    class NetworkManager {
        static let shared = NetworkManager()
        
        func request<T: Codable>(type: T.Type,
                                 url: String,
                                 method: HTTPMethod,
                                 completion: @escaping((Result<T, ErrorTypes>)->())) {
            AF.request(url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? " ", method: method).responseData { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    self.handleResponse(data: data) { response in
                        completion(response)
    
                    }
                case .failure(_):
                    completion(.failure(.generalError))
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        fileprivate func handleResponse<T: Codable>(data: Data,completion: @escaping((Result<T, ErrorTypes>)->())){
            do{
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(result))
            }
            catch{
                completion(.failure(.invalidData))
            }
        }
        
    }
```

- HomeHelper

```
    import Foundation
    
    enum HomeEndpoint: String {
        case popular = "movie/popular"
        
        var path: String {
            switch self{
            case.popular:
                return NetworkHelper.shared.requestUrl(url: HomeEndpoint.popular.rawValue)
    
            }
        }
    }
```

-HomeManager

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeManagerProtocol {
    func getCatagoryMovies(complete:@escaping((Movie?,Error?)->()))
}

class HomeManager{
    static let shared = HomeManager()
    
    func getCatagoryMovies(complete:@escaping((Movie?,Error?)->())){
        NetworkManager.shared.request(type: Movie.self,
                                      url: HomeEndpoint.popular.path,
                                      method:.get) { response in
            switch response{
            case .success(let data):
                complete(data,nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                complete(nil,error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

-Movie

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Movie
struct Movie: Codable {
    let page: Int?
    let results: [MovieResult]?
    let totalPages, totalResults: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case page, results
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case totalResults = "total_results"
    }
}

// MARK: - MovieResult
struct MovieResult: Codable  {
    let adult: Bool?
    let backdropPath: String?
    let genreIDS: [Int]?
    let id: Int?
    let originalLanguage, originalTitle, overview: String?
    let popularity: Double?
    let posterPath, releaseDate, title: String?
    let video: Bool?
    let voteAverage: Double?
    let voteCount: Int?
    let character, creditID: String?
    let order: Int?
    let department, job: String?
}
```

-HomeViewModel

```
import Foundation


class HomeViewModel{
    let manager = HomeManager.shared
    
    var movie: Movie?
    var errorCallBack: ((String)->())?
    var successCallBack: (()->())?
    
    func getCatagoryItems(){
        manager.getCatagoryMovies { [weak self ]Movie, error in
            if let error = error{
                self?.errorCallBack?(error.localizedDescription)

            }else{
                self?.movie = Movie
                self?.successCallBack?()
            }
        }
    }
   
    
    func numberOfItems() -> Int{
        movie?.results?.count ?? 0
        
    }
}
```

-HomeViewController

```
import UIKit

class  HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionSetup()
        viewModelConfiguration()
        
        
    }
    
    fileprivate func collectionSetup(){
        collectionView.registerCell(type: VerticalCollectionViewCell.self)
    }
    
    fileprivate func viewModelConfiguration(){
        
        viewModel.getCatagoryItems()
        viewModel.errorCallBack = { [weak self] errorMesage in
            print("error: \(errorMesage)")
        }
        viewModel.successCallBack = { [weak self] in
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            
        }
    }


}
extension HomeViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.numberOfItems()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: VerticalCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueCell(for: indexPath)
        print(viewModel.movie?.results?[indexPath.item].originalTitle ?? "")
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
        
    }
        
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width * 327 / 375, height: 120)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 365)

    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging.  Xcode has a really powerful debugger built in. You can set breakpoints (i suggest you start in `viewModelConfiguration` and step through. You can also set breakpoints in your completion handlers since they will be called asynchronously. It could even be that you are getting the data but your collection view layout is wrong and you aren't displaying it.

Comment: Please update your question to only include relevant code. And please provide at least some details about what issue you are having.

Comment: For example, you have included some protocols but they aren't used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the `originalTitle` to display because you are not
decoding the server response with the correct data model, specifically `MovieResult`.

Try this, works for me:

```
 struct MovieResult: Identifiable, Codable {  // <-- here
     let id: Int
     let adult, video: Bool
     let genreIDS: [Int]
     let originalLanguage, originalTitle, overview: String
     let posterPath, releaseDate, title, backdropPath: String
     let popularity, voteAverage: Double
     let voteCount: Int

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {  // <-- here
         case adult, id, title, video, overview, popularity
         case backdropPath = "backdrop_path"
         case genreIDS = "genre_ids"
         case originalLanguage = "original_language"
         case originalTitle = "original_title"
         case posterPath = "poster_path"
         case releaseDate = "release_date"
         case voteAverage = "vote_average"
         case voteCount = "vote_count"
     }
 }
```